# SharePoint In the Cloud

Tags: sharepoint, cloud, rest

How to retrieve *Modified By* field from SharePoint for the folders.  I can retrieve *Modified By* field for files, but was not able find away to do the same for folders.  I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with REST API to get the file and folder information and able to do so.  Unfortunately, *Modified by* field for folders returns only nulls, but the folders on the SharePoint site display/show *Modified By* field.

Comment: Amos_MSFT thank you, that works to get 'Modified By' field, but I loose information such Name,TimeCreated.  I needed Name,TimeCreated and Editor/Title for folders and files. I was using GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('xxx/xxx/Shared Documents/') and was able  to get Name,TimeCreated.  How do I combine these methods? Do I need to make separate calls and map the returned data in memory?

Comment: Essentially wanted like this:                                                                                                
[
 {
        "name": "Accounting",
        "timeCreated": "04/09/2020 15:56:21",
        "title": Jonh Jonhson,
        "serverRelativeUrl": "/sites/xxxxx/Shared Documents/Accounting"
    },
    {
        "name": "Admin, Mtgs, Presentations",
        "timeCreated": "04/09/2020 15:56:21",
        "title": Peter Smith,
        "serverRelativeUrl": "/sites/xxxx/Shared Documents/Admin, Mtgs, Presentations"
    },
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this endpoint to get Modified By (editor).

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('lib')/items(3)?$select=Editor/Title&$expand=Editor
```

Whether it is a folder or a file, you can get the editor .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating to MS Graph API usage and was able to query data with just one Rest API call and retrieve the needed information on both folders and files.